# Android SurfaceView thread

Tags: android, surfaceview

I  created custom SurfaceView which contains circles. And I want to rotate this circle using touch events. But I do not understand when thread of SurfaceView must pause and resume. 
If the thread must run all time when app is active or only when the circle rotates??? 
I run LunarLander sample and in this app thread running all time when app is active. 
whether it is right or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SurfaceView` doesn't have its own thread.It can be drawn by background threads.

There is a distinction

*Should you Keep the thread running?*

Well it depends whether there is a point to the thread. If you need to keep it running. Obviously if you don't need to you shouldn't.

If the thread has to pick up the touch events I suggest you leave it on

Comment: @ Carl Saldanha "SurfaceView doesn't have its own thread" I meant thread in which surfaceView is drawing. Thanks for help)

Comment: Okay. Makes sense then :-) Thought I should mention. Threads obviously waste battery (not enough to really matter) but it depends really on how many updates your doing on it.